# Adding an extra button in facebook post using google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was successful to track all "uiStreamSource" that holds the link associated with each facebook post (status, image, etc) to add one extra button next to the date to do some other tasks using google chrome extensions. This button does a predefined job which not important to mention in this context.

I wrote this content script:

> contentscript.js

```
var nodeslist=document.getElementsByClassName("uiStreamSource");
alert(nodeslist.length);
```

Each time a facebook page is loaded, the alert shows me 10 detected classes (i.e., 10 posts). But when I scroll down, new posts show up and this code fails to detect them. Since I need to update all uiStreamSource nodes in all posts, how can I solve this?

**UPDATE**

I tried this code in contentscript.js:

```
load();
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument", load, false);

function load(){
    var nodeslist=document.getElementsByClassName("uiStreamSource");
    alert(nodeslist.length);
}
```

The first time it runs, I get the correct number of the current nodes (current facebook posts) but once I scroll down and more posts are fetched, the alert shows up indicating that load function is called but the number of nodes printed is 0. Why is that?

Thanks on advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `DOMNodeInserted` event and check if the element that is going to be inserted is a post by checking its classes.

Or an easy solution is to use the [jcade](https://github.com/snesin/jcade) plugin. It  can call a callback function when an element with specified selector is inserted.

Comment: I used your first advice and wrote this code down
contentscript.js

    load();
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentInserted", load, false);

    function load(){
     var nodeslist=document.getElementsByClassName("uiStreamSource");
     alert(nodeslist.length);
    }


The result was: the first time the alert shows 10 posts which good. When I scroll down, new posts show up and the alert also shows but with value 0. There must be something wrong, can you give me a pointer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the scroll event and add any new posts to `nodeslist`. You could use setInterval as well to catch any posts that are added when the user is not scrolling.